# Pytest is throwing warning string>:1: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \s

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

When I execute pytest unit tests, I am getting following warning

> qualys/tests/test_scan.py::TestQualysScan::test_w   string>:1:
>   DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \s

I have searched for any `'\s'` in my code and few I found were in raw string (`r'...'`) so it shouldn't be problem.

I also not getting meaning of `1` in

> string>:1:

Should it be string or line number?

Do you have any suggestion how to fix it or how to get exact line number?

```
class TestQualysScan:
    def test_w(self, mock_mysqlApi, mock_qualysRequest):
        test_scan = QualysScan(mock_qualysRequest(), 'EMEA', [mock_qualysServer], 'test_scan',
                               mysqlApi=mock_mysqlApi(ops_server_table_sample[0]))
        assert True
```

and fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_mysqlApi():
    def _mock_mysqlApi_factory (db_entry_dict):
        mock_mysqlApi = MagicMock(spec=MysqlApi)
        mock_cursor = MagicMock(spec=DictCursorLogged)
        mock_mysqlApi.get_cursor().__enter__.return_value = mock_cursor
        mock_cursor.fetchone.return_value = db_entry_dict
        mock_cursor.fetchall.return_value = db_entry_dict

        return mock_mysqlApi
    return _mock_mysqlApi_factory
```

and

```
@pytest.fixture
def instance_qualysRequest(mock_mysqlApi, mock_qualysApi):
    def _qualysRequest_factory(data):
        test_request = QualysRequest(data['id'], qualysApi=mock_qualysApi, mysqlApi=mock_mysqlApi(data))
        return test_request
    return _qualysRequest_factory
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code from `TestQualysScan` to your question.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Are you running the code on Windows, and the current directory starts with s, like `C:\Users\sakalos`?

Comment: @roland - no is jsakalos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have configured pytest to handle warning as error (-W), so it reported exact line with error and i was able to identify issue:

```
 pytest.py -srapP -W error::DeprecationWarning -v
```

Comment: Helped me fixed the same problem, originating in imported code. Had a path as "c:\dblabla...." just need to change it to c:\\dblabla